# Grouping in SQL flat table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have both Email and Phone together in one table. Both Email and Phone have their own effective date. I want to get a Master record grouped by ID column  with the most recent email and the most recent phone. Thank you.

**Below is my Table**

```
ID  Email       Email_Date  Phone       Phone_Date
1   abc@t.com   2019-09-28  4151234567  2018-09-28
1   def@t.com   2018-09-28  4150000000  2019-09-28
2   xyz@t.com   2018-09-28  3150004567  2019-09-28
2   opx@t.com   2019-09-28  3151234567  2018-09-28
```

**This is Expected outcome**

```
ID  Email       PHone
1   abc@t.com   4150000000
2   opx@t.com   3150004567
```

Comment: @Larnu this is not the case of any of the duplicate links you propose. I thought so when I first read the question, but I missed the part that the 2 max values that need to be returned do not come from the same row.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, @forpas. Personally then, I see this as a design flaw; the OP would be better with a single row version value. It also appears to make no sense that a row inserted later can have an earlier value for something else. I'll unlock but *something* here is wrong with the OP's design or way they are processing/inserting their data

Comment: *It also appears to make no sense that a row inserted later can have an earlier value* exactly!

Answer (score 0):

You want results from different rows for each id, so do a trick by concatenating the date to the email or phone to obtain the max date:

```
with cte as (
  select id,
    max(concat(email_date, email)) email,
    max(concat(phone_date, phone)) phone
  from tablename
  group by id
)
select id,
  substring(email, 20, len(email)) email,
  substring(phone, 20, len(phone)) phone
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31a42a2bfc19555aee936a191162704d).
Results:

```
> id | email     | phone     
> -: | :-------- | :---------
>  1 | abc@t.com | 4150000000
>  2 | opx@t.com | 3150004567
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comments, something seems "wrong" here; how do you `INSERT` a row at a latter date that has the "latest" value for `Phone`, but somehow has an older version for `Email`? This "smells" like whatever process you're using to `INSERT` the data has a flaw. Really you should have a single column for the row version; a design like this is going to be really hard to maintain.

This would mean that your data might look more like this:

```
ID  Email      Phone       Updated_Date
1   def@t.com  4151234567  2018-09-28
1   def@t.com  4150000000  2019-09-28
1   abc@t.com  4150000000  2019-09-28
```

Note that the above means there were 2 changes on the same date (one reverting the value of email); so you need to extra version ID column (an `IDENTITY` column would work fine) *or* you'd need to include the time of the change as well as the date. Without either the addition of the version ID, or the time then you have no way of knowing which of the final 2 rows is the "correct" one (as you can't figure it out using an `ORDER BY` and tables don't store the data in the "order it was inserted").

Anyway, the method I would use is *similar* to those that I previously marked as a duplicate (still using `ROW_NUMBER`), but adding some conditional aggregation:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Email,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Email_Date DESC) AS Email_RN,
           Phone,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Phone_Date DESC) AS Phone_RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE Email_RN WHEN 1 THEN Email END) AS Email,
       MAX(CASE Phone_RN WHEN 1 THEN Phone END) AS Phone
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: @Larnu isn't a GROUP BY clause missing?

Comment: Glad to have helped @PaulW. . If this was the answer, please do vote up and/or marked the answer as solution. Thanks.